# Logging renders?

Tags: rendering, workflow

Is there a simple way to log/save every render that you make in a Blender scene? Maybe an add-on? This would be helpful to visually see progress on modeling, materials, lighting, and whatnot. It would also be helpful if it could "print on" the date/time, vertex count, and the camera settings. Am I just dreaming or is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The closest thing to *logging* a render in Blender is to render to different slots. Each slot can store a different render for comparisons etc. In the Image Editor, there is a popup menu in the header that has 8 different slots that you can render to. Before rendering, choose a slot. *( You can also quickly cycle through these by using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> for the previous render slot and <kbd>J</kbd> for next render slot.)*

[image]

As for the second part, there is a *Stamp* pane in the *Render* tab that you can use to attach the date, time and render time etc to your render.

[image]

Comment: stamp is acceptable, but unfortunately not a greatly customizable feature at the moment :/

Comment: @zeffii, stamp options are written into metadata of EXR/JPEG/PNG files. So if you dont want to see them, you can use a tool to read them back (exrheader command for openexr for example).

Comment: @ideasman42 It gets written to the metadata? Then why is there text color and background options?

Comment: @Dan the Man, because `Stamp` button is pressed, if its not, the metadata still gets written to the file.

Comment: @ideasman42 So `Stamp` prints it on to the image, but by default it already gets written to the file?

Comment: @Dan the Man. correct

Comment: @ideasman42 - In what metadata format does Blender store Stamp info in PNGs? I'm struggling to find the RenderTime value with ExifTool

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2653/55 - checked and the metadata is stored and readable.

Comment: Thanks, I have now found the metadata. For posterity, the process appears to be enable Stamp -> Select tags -> Disable Stamp - > Find metadata info now in PNG header

Answer (score 12):

You can have Blender automatically save files if you check the Auto Save checkbox in the render settings.

[image: autosave checkbox]

Renders will automatically be saved to `*blendfile location*/auto_save/`. If you check subfolders renders will be saved to: `*blendfile location*/auto_save/*blendfile name*/`(useful if you have multiple .blend files saved in the same directory)

Since it uses the location of the .blend file as a base, you must save your file before this feature can work.

It is an [addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/Auto_Save), so make sure to enable it in the settings:
[image: enable in the settings]

Comment: I'm using 2.67a, and the setting doesn't exist, even on saved file. Is it an addon?

Comment: @Adhi it is. I added that just added that to the answer.

Comment: Wow, I need to check out the installed addons more. Its support level is Testing, filtered off by default in my install. Thanks for pointing that one out :)

Comment: @Gwenn: It wasn't included in 2.66a. In fact, not a single addon with support level Testing is included before 2.67 IIRC (it's there by the heapload in 2.67a).

Comment: @Adhi I can't find it in 2.67a. Even with "testing" checked.

Comment: Testing addons are never in releases, they need to be approved first. - Contact bf-python mailing list to suggest inclusion.

Comment: I don't know Blender's policy about this, but I downloaded blender-2.67a-linux-glibc211-i686.tar.bz2 fresh off download.blender.org and there they are in scripts/addons_contrib. All 4.2MBs of it, including render_auto_save.py. Maybe something went wrong with 32bit Linux release?

Comment: I've just downloaded 2.67b, and addons_contrib is no longer included. So it's not supposed to be there in the first place... :D

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar need before and I did a test. By making use of the handlers (bpy.app.handlers), once can define render_pre, render_post, render_complete callbacks on render (bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.append(preRenderFunc), etc.,).

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def PostLoadSession(self):
    print("post load")
    scene = bpy.context.scene
    srrid = 'srrid'
    if srrid not in scene or not scene[srrid]:
        print("Nothing was rendered previously")
    else:
        print('Last image rendered was {0}.{1}.png'.format('RenderResult' ,scene[srrid]))

bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(PostLoadSession)

@persistent
def PreRender(self):
    print("pre render")
    scene = bpy.context.scene
    srrid = 'srrid'
    if srrid not in scene:
        print('This is the first time you are rendering from this file')
        scene[srrid] = 0
        print('Created {0}'.format(srrid)) 

bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.append(PreRender)

@persistent
def PostRender(self):
    print("post render")
    scene = bpy.context.scene
    srrid = 'srrid'
    if srrid not in scene:
        print('PreRender was not called')
    else:
        scene[srrid] += 1
        print('Saved render result as {0}.{1}.png'.format('RenderResult', scene[srrid])) 

bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.append(PostRender)
```

You can find more details on my blog post.

http://learningblender3dsoftware.blogspot.in/2012/10/messing-around-with-prepost-handlers.html

The code available on my blog does not actually save the images yet, but it can be easily achievable. I am actually in the process of creating an add-on that saves the images. I hope to release a beta version soon.