# Keeping old renders open

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to learn materials, and there are **so many options!** I'd like to be able to compare side by side the effect of changing certain values.

Is it possible to keep old renders open?

Comment: What do you mean by old renders, the last rendered image and so forth etc? Possible duplicate of [Logging Renders](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/463/logging-renders)

Comment: That's what I mean, yes. There doesn't seem to be a way to view two different slots at the same time, however.

Comment: Cant you create more views? Closing as a dupe.

Comment: Changing the slot on one view updates all of the other views to the same slot!

Comment: There are some other suggestions there, the second one might be of more use then.. as it writes the files to disk.

Comment: Hmm not idea, but I suppose I'm being overly picky :s

Comment: possibly.. :) I usually just cycle through these quickly using shortcuts, `Alt + J` and `J`..

Comment: Is there a way to clear slots I'm no longer interested in (google isn't giving me much)

Comment: I don't think so, you can overwrite these as necessary as they are temporary or just leave them, they won't affect anything.