# How can we store EXIF-type metadata in renders?

Tags: workflow

I used Blender this afternoon to turn a panorama into an extremely wide-angled photograph. This got me wondering: would it make any sense to store EXIF data in images generated by Cycles so you get the FOV, ISO, Arpeture, and so on? Especially since HDR formats are like the digital equivalent to taking a picture, I can see it being useful for making accurate composites, faking camera shake, and other things. Do Radiance HDR or OpenEXR keep track of that sort of metadata? I tried looking around and couldn't find anything. How do professionals keep track of that meta data in their renders or does nobody care?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/463/logging-renders/464#464

Comment: You can now store metadata in renders this way: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/output/properties/metadata.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender can handle the complete pipe line from modelling to video editing. In such a workflow the data is always available and doesn't need to be exported elsewhere. For comparing renders the norm is to just *[Stamp](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/post_process/metadata.html)* the images.

Let me quote [ideasman42](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/463/logging-renders/464#comment-594):

> stamp options are written into metadata of EXR/JPEG/PNG files. So if you dont want to see them, you can use a tool to read them back (exrheader command for openexr for example).

There isn't *yet* [a standard for storing EXIF data in the OpenEXR format](http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/openexr-devel/2013-07/msg00039.html), so it's unlikely this data will show up in other applications.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any option to add this data from within Blender, but I would think an extension would be the best solution (there are already options for [timestamps and other such simple info](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/463/logging-renders/464#464) IIRC).

For now, a possible solution would be to use a 3rd party application such as [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) to add this information to the file.

Comment: That link to the other stackexchange question on logging was a good enough resource! It seems that saving to EXR saves the camera, lens, and scene metadata along with other kinds of useful information whether or not you stamp it onto the image itself. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

For me I find exiv2 command line works fine to add needed fields. EX:
exiv2 -M"set Exif.Image.Model RICOH THETA S" untitled7.png
exiv2 -M"set Exif.Image.Make RICOH" untitled7.png

Then can confirm / view it like:
exiv2 untitled7.png | less