# Read image metadata produced by Blender?

Tags: rendering, file-format

After reading the comments under [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/464/599), I was wondering how to view this data in rendered images?

I tried looking in the comment and such places with [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/), and `file` but found nothing.

It seems this metadata is printed regardless of whether or not [*Stamp*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Post_Process/Stamp) is enabled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:**
[As of 2.75](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.75/More_Features#Metadata_support) this data is saved for all renders.

---

This info is written to the header of the file and only for auto saved renders (animations and command-line renders). For info on how to read the headers see the documentation for the relevant format. I don't believe GIMP has a way to view this data. As [ideasman42 said](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/463/logging-renders/464#comment-594), for EXR files you can use `exrheader` which is included in the [OpenEXR](http://www.openexr.com) package, for PNG and JPEG files you can use `identify -verbose` command from the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) package.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to read the image metadata from Python?

Answer (score 4):

I only tested this for png files, so it might be different for other formats.

The metadata is written to the file as plain text, so you can view it using any text viewer, even notepad.
By simply opening one of my renders in notepad, I got this:
[image]

It may look like a complete mess, but you can easily find the information if you take a closer look.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah... So it writes it as additional `tEXt` chunks in the PNG stream? That should mean any program that can parse PNG chunks should be able to read this... interesting...

Answer (score -1):

The data is printed onto the image as text. You can view the data by looking at the image.

If you want to parse it, you could try OCR of some sort. It may help to set the stamp background to full opacity so that there's no image interference. OCR should then be very accurate.

Comment: This is incorrect, the info is written into metadata as well (for image formats which blender can write metadata into (PNG, EXR, JPEG))

Comment: Using OCR still seems like huge overkill and likerly error prone, when you can read the image as text from the file using existing tools to extract meta-data from the header.

Comment: @WChargin I meant how to read the stamp data that is to be written to the image metadata, not into the pixels themselves. sorry the original question wasn't very clear