# How to display render stamp outside the frame?

Tags: rendering, image

How would it be possible to have the render stamp information displayed outside the frame and also how to customize their font, opacity and position like so?:

[image]
(Click the image for larger version)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Custom Render Stamp

[image: stamp]
(Click the image for larger version)

Based on [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26644) by Campbell Barton, I made a small very crappy script to put the render stamp outside the rendered frame by using the render border.

It sure could be improved by a million percent, but for my petty purposes it's good enough.
(Although, all improvement suggestions are of course full-heartedly welcomed!)

---

### **Installation**

- Download the Script and open it in the text editor
- Adjust the settings to your liking
- Press *Run Script*
- Enable the *Register* option in the text editor (so it runs automatically)

### **Usage**

- Define the **Monitor Aspect** ratio in the script's settings. The script expands the frame vertically until the defined aspect ratio is met.

> For example, if the **Monitor Aspect** setting in the script is set to 16:9, a 2048x858 (2.39:1) sized camera frame gets expanded (not stretched) vertically to 2048x1152 (16:9).
>
> *In other words, stuff gets added to the top and the bottom of the frame.*

- Define the **Frame Resolution** in the script's settings. The script resizes the render border accordingly.

> For example, if the **Frame Resolution** is set to 2048x858, only that sized border render will be rendered out of the full 2048x1152 frame. The rest will be seen as black (or transparent) along with the stamp information.
>
> *In other words, the same amount of stuff gets removed from the top and the bottom of the frame and the stamp gets added.*

- If you change the **percent** value of the **render resolution**, run the script again in order to make the stamp's font size to adjust nicely to the correct size.

---

### **Download: [custom_render_stamp.py](http://docs.manujarvinen.com/custom_render_stamp.py)**

---

```
##############################################################
#                                                            #
#                   CUSTOM RENDER STAMP                      #
#                                                            #
##############################################################
#                                                            #
#                        Settings                            #
#                        --------                            #

# Define names to the render stamp:
Animator = 'Pedro'
Compositor = 'Fabio'

# Define the name of the scene:
Scene_Name = 'Scene'

# Define render frame resolution (without the stamp sections):
Frame_Resolution_X = 2048
Frame_Resolution_Y = 858

# Define desired full frame aspect ratio (stamp section size):
Monitor_Aspect_X = 16
Monitor_Aspect_Y = 9

##############################################################
#                                                            #
#                         Script                             #
#                         ------                             #

resx = Frame_Resolution_X
resy = Frame_Resolution_Y
aspx = Monitor_Aspect_X
aspy = Monitor_Aspect_Y

# For example 2048x858's height inside 1920x1080 (= 804)
#~ aspx / resx * resy

# For example 1920x1080's upper stamp section height (= 138)
#~ (aspy - aspx / resx * resy) / 2

# For example 2048x1152's upper stamp section height (= 147)
Stamp_Height = resx / aspx * (aspy - aspx / resx * resy) / 2

# Full frame height (= 1152)
Full_Frame_Height = resy + 2 * Stamp_Height

# Render Stamp:
import bpy
import socket

# Uncomment to automatically use the name of the current scene:
# Scene_Name = bpy.context.scene.name

def stamp_set(scene):

    render = scene.render
    Render_Percent = render.resolution_percentage
    is_cycles = (render.engine == 'CYCLES')

    render.use_stamp_note = True
    render.stamp_note_text = (
        "Samples: {samples}  |  "
        "Aperture Radius: {aperture:.4f}  |  "
        "Blender {ver} {branch} {hash}  |  "
        "Resolution: {res_x} x {res_y}  |  "
        "Animator: {anim}  |  "
        "Compositor: {comp}  |  "
        "Rendernode: {hostname}"
    ).format(
        samples=scene.cycles.samples if is_cycles else render.antialiasing_samples,
        aperture=scene.camera.data.cycles.aperture_size if is_cycles else "NONE",
        ver=bpy.app.version_string,
        branch=bpy.app.build_branch,
        hash=bpy.app.build_hash,
        res_x=int(render.resolution_x * Render_Percent / 100),
        res_y=int(render.resolution_y * (1 - Stamp_Height * 2 / Full_Frame_Height) * Render_Percent / 100),
        hostname=socket.gethostname(),
        anim=Animator,
        comp=Compositor,
        )

bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.append(stamp_set)

# Set Render Resolution Width:
bpy.data.scenes[Scene_Name].render.resolution_x = Frame_Resolution_X

# Use Render Border:
bpy.data.scenes[Scene_Name].render.use_border = True

# Render Stamp font size:
bpy.data.scenes[Scene_Name].render.stamp_font_size = 18 * bpy.data.scenes[Scene_Name].render.resolution_percentage / 100

# Set Render Borders:
bpy.data.scenes[Scene_Name].render.resolution_y = Full_Frame_Height
bpy.data.scenes[Scene_Name].render.border_min_y = Stamp_Height / Full_Frame_Height
bpy.data.scenes[Scene_Name].render.border_max_y = 1 - Stamp_Height / Full_Frame_Height
```

Answer (score 3):

No, Blender can't do this, if you want the image without having text overlayed on it, you can extract the information from the image though.
(See: [Read image metadata produced by Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/read-image-metadata-produced-by-blender))

Some image viewers will display meta-data along side the image too.