# Can't find EXIF informations in JPG and PNG output files

Tags: rendering, file-format

In a previous comment, [ideasman42](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/463/logging-renders/464#comment-594) explains : *stamp options are written into metadata of EXR/JPEG/PNG files*.

But I can't find any EXIF information in JPG and PNG files generated by Blender (version 2.78).

Enabling *Meta Data* in the *Render* tab does not change anything...

### Edit :

After some investigations, I realized that stamp informations are stored in the image file as JPEG markers and not in EXIF format...

Metadata can be displayed with a JPEG utility like jpeginfo :

```
$ jpeginfo -C untitled.jpg 
untitled.jpg  960 x 540  24bit JFIF  N   13028 
"Blender:File:<untitled>"  "Blender:Note:dominique Parisot"
"Blender:Date:2017/08/17 19:46:52" "Blender:Time:00:00:00:01"
"Blender:Frame:001" "Blender:Camera:Camera" "Blender:Scene:Scene"
"Blender:RenderTime:00:00.05"
```

But they can not be found with an EXIF utility like exiv2 :

```
$ exiv2 untitled.jpg 
File name       : untitled.jpg
File size       : 13028 Bytes
MIME type       : image/jpeg
Image size      : 960 x 540
untitled.jpg: No Exif data found in the file
```

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/read-image-metadata-produced-by-blender/2653#2653

Comment: @RayMairlot :  thank you for your response. I used **exiv2** to verify that blender output files do not contain any EXIF information :  `$ exiv2 untitled.jpg
File name       : untitled.jpg
File size       : 20692 Bytes
MIME type       : image/jpeg
Image size      : 960 x 540
untitled.jpg: No Exif data found in the file`

Comment: If you have additional information to add to your question please use the [edit] link below it instead of comments.