# How to find which machine rendered a specific frame in a render farm

Tags: rendering, command-line, network

I have 6 servers rendering the same project (not using the Network Render add-on). All of the servers are exporting into a shared network folder.

Some frames have issues; how can I find the faulty machine?

Comment: What are the "issues"? What makes a frame "faulty"?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding custom metadata to the image using a Python script that is executed by each server. In the network folder, create a script named `metadata.py` with the following code:

```
import bpy, socket

name = socket.gethostname()

bpy.context.scene.render.use_stamp_note = True
bpy.context.scene.render.stamp_note_text = name
```

In your render command, add the `-P` flag with the path to the script, e.g.

```
blender -b path/to/file.blend -P path/to/metadata.py -o path/to/image.png -a
```

This stores the name of the machine in the "Note" section of Blender's metadata. You can view the metadata as described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2653/26640) to see which server is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a very efficient way to do this, but in case you can't find a better solution you could have each machine render the same frame, then look which machine was unable to render it properly.

Comment: maybe something with metadata settings