# No file output after rendering?

Tags: rendering

I usually am able to render successfully to the `c:\tmp` folder, but when I came into work today, I rendered out the image on my work laptop, and everything seems to work, but I'm not getting an output to the tmp directory.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to render an animation or a still image?

Comment: Your File Explorer window shows 'Windows...tmp', are you sure you are looking in the right place? There should be a folder called tmp in the root of C:\ drive.

Comment: If any of the answers presented helped you, please remember to upvote them and mark one as Accepted.

Comment: @Keavon, understood. Ive been on SE for awhile, just a noob here :)

Comment: No problem. Welcome to Blender.SE :)

Comment: i found a really cool fix for this here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0DrapAQSlbU

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As an extension of [Keavon's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6771/599), Blender does not write still renders to the hard drive by default in the GUI. Command line renders *are* written to the hard drive automatically, and there is an [addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/Auto_Save) which adds this functionality in the GUI. (see [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/491/599)).

There are a few ways to work around this:

- Render a one frame animation as in [Keavon's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6771/599).
- Save the image manually from the *UV/Image editor* after the render is complete (press <kbd>F3</kbd> with the cursor in the image editor, or select the option from the header):

  [image]

  For 2.8 Use the Image Editor, and select Image > Save As (or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)

  [image]

  You will be taken to the *File Browser* with options to set the format and location of the saved image:

  [image]
- Render by running [`bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_10/bpy.ops.render.html?#bpy.ops.render.render) in the [*Python Console*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Console). The render will be written to the output path.
- Use a *[File Output node](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Types/Output#File_Output_Node)* as [mentioned by Matt](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6769/no-file-output-after-rendering/6772#comment10785_6772):

  [image]

  This will create a file `/tmp/test.png`. Note that the *File output node* has format and output path settings in the *Properties region* (<kbd>N</kbd>) which are separate from the scene settings.

Comment: There is also a contrib addon that will autosave still renders - [wiki page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/Auto_Save)

Comment: @sambler I already mentioned it (though I forgot the link). Thanks :)

Comment: Will adding a file output node also solve this problem, or do you still have to manually save a single frame render?

Comment: @Matt Good point. Yes, a file output will autosave still renders.

Answer (score 11):

**It sounds like you're rendering a preview, not the image.**

If you already rendered your image, push <kbd>F3</kbd> to save it as [originally suggested in Gandalf's answer.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6772/743)

**However, if you want to render it and get a file without having to touch it later, follow these steps:**

*I suggest you first set your output directory to your desktop or another non-temporary place:*

[image: Output directory]

**To start,**
Set your animation length to 1 frame long, like this:

[image: Animation Length]

Now make sure you have the proper image file output format selected, like PNG:

[image: PNG file format]

Now hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> to render the "animation" (which is actually the one frame) or click *Render* > *Render Animation*:

[image: Render Animation]

After your single frame finishes rendering, you will have the image on your desktop or wherever you set the output.

Comment: Thanks - Render animation does work.  But, really, I just want to render single images.

Comment: @Simon You can save the still manually with `F3`, see my answer.