# Render not being saved

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

When I render my image, it renders perfectly fine, but it doesn't save out.

Can anyone explain how to get my image to save after rendering?

Comment: Are you getting a black render?

Comment: do you have a light and a camera in your scene?

Comment: Please add mote information. Post an image of you render settings an any other info you feel is relevant to yiur issue. The easiest way to determine what's wrong is by uploading your file.

Comment: I edited you question to work with the information that you provided on taco dudes answer. If you don't like it, feel free to revert it, but if you do, please change it to explain your issue better.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6769/599

Answer (score 3):

After you render out your image, press F3 in the UV image editor for the Save Image As function. You can also go to *Image* -> *Save As Image*.

I recommend checking out [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6772/8262) by gandalf3 which provides more detail as well as solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You might be forgetting to specify the location of the file.  The default location of the render is in the tmp directory.  Try checking that, but your computer might not have a tmp directory.  On Windows, the tmp directory is in C:\tmp.

Comment: Blender doesn't render the image there by default. Also, this is an issue with rendering, not saving.

Comment: Really?  It says /tmp\ and when I accidentally forget to specify the location, I find my render in the C:\tmp directory.

Comment: In your output tab, do you have cache result enabled?

Comment: I do see a checkbox in the output tab in the Render section called "Cache R..." that is unchecked.

Comment: yeah i made sure of the file i was rendering it to was set

Comment: i tried with cache result and without

Comment: it even gives me the option to view the render but then when i click it it takes me to the file directory but no picture.

Comment: @zion so does the render show up in the UV Image editor when it's done then? If it does, try saving it out with the "F3" key.

Comment: and yes it renders in the software but it doesent render out

Comment: no it does not render in the uv image editor, only when i press render

Comment: thank you guys i finally got it to save as image special thanks to TARDIS maker for the idea. i tried it once and it did not work but i reloaded blender and saved the file out