# How to save render?

Tags: rendering

Every time I render an image and try to save it, it just disappears. How do you exactly save a render? I am using a mac.

Comment: **Shift-S** on Blender v2.80 and later.

**F3** on on Blender v2.79 and earlier.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6769/599

Answer (score 38):

If you render a single frame by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>, it won't be saved by default. It will occupy one of the render result slots, untill you render a frame again. In the *UV/Image Editor*, where you can see the rendered result, you can easily save it by going to *Image > Save As Image*, or by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd>:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If by disappears you mean it gets back to 3d view then you should be able to switch the view back to image editor and open last render result.

[image]

Otherwise you can also use Output field in your rendering settings to save the render in wanted location. (But as Tardis noted in a comment, you need to use rendering as animation and set frame range to a single frame to output the image to the location.)

[image]

Comment: From my experience, the Output location field only works with animations.

Comment: @TAR By default yes, but you can adjust the hotkey F12 for example to render and write, which will write a still to that loction after render completion.

Answer (score 6):

As other answers mentioned, Blender doesn't save stills by default, but you can change that if you're alright with writing a tiny bit of python (barely writing any).

If you right-click the "Render" button and select "Edit Source" you can then switch to the text editor, and in the files menu (the button next to "Templates" drop down) you can see properties_render.py file there. When you click it, a cursor will be at the line "defining" the button in the GUI.
At the end of the line, just append `.write_still = True`.
If you do that, it will automatically save stills to the output directory you set (the same directory where the rendered animation frames are saved to as well).

Note: If you're on Windows and have Blender installed to the default location (Program Files, usually), you may have to run it as administrator in order to edit the file. Also note, that the safest way to apply the change is to restart Blender after saving the file (Alt + S, or just use the Text dropdown menu and select the Save item).
Congrats! Now your Blender installation will automatically save stills by default to the output directory you set for the project.

**Update:**

For Blender 2.8 and later, you will need to right click the render menu label in the menu bar at the top. This will open up the correct file, but not in the correct place. To do that, you'll need to copy (CTRL+C) the contents of the string on the highlighted line (In Blender 2.90, it is `TOPBAR_MT_render`), and then use the find function (CTRL+F) to find the definition of the menu.

Once you find it, you'll see something like this:

```
layout.operator("render.render", text="Render Image", icon='RENDER_STILL')
```

If there's anything following this, like `.use_viewport = True`, edit the source so it looks like this:

```
stills = layout.operator("render.render", text="Render Image",
                icon='RENDER_STILL')
stills.use_viewport = True
stills.write_still = True
```

Otherwise, you can just append `.write_still = True` to that line.

Comment: can you share the full new py file? it's not clear where to add .write_still = True

Comment: @Sanbaldo when you right click the "Edit Source" on the "Render" button, the cursor should be on the correct line. As for using the file with Blender 2.8X, it probably won't be compatible.

Comment: which "render" button are you referring? header? clicking with right mouse doesn't show up that "edit source" option.

Comment: @Sanbaldo this is a question (and answer) from back when the Render button was in the panel with scene properties. Not sure what to change/fix in the 2.8+ versions.

Comment: @Sanbaldo idk if you managed to figure it out, or don't need it anymore, but the answer has been updated with the solution for 2.8+ versions

Comment: Thanks for the update!

Comment: It worked! perfect!

Comment: the only problem is that the still is saved always with the same name..

Comment: You'll have to change the output filename for that in the scene properties. Can't help you much else with that.

Answer (score 5):

### How to AUTO-SAVE render (still image)

### Option 1

*Addon* **Auto Save Render** saves still image render automatically ...

[image]

Notes:

- Addon is bundled with Experimental (daily) build, for official release you have to [download it from here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAC/browse/master/render_auto_save.py) and install version 2.1 or higher for Blender 2.8 and above.
- Auto-saved files are located in the same directory as your .blend file inside folder "auto_save".
  So ... to take the script works you have to save your .blend file first.

### Option 2

*Compositor editor >* <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Output >* **File Output** node also saves render automatically ...

[image]

### Option 3

Manually save in **Image editor** *> Image > Save as* <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

[image]

### Option 4

... a bit funny option, but also option ... set animation as a one frame (same start/end frame).

[image]

Comment: auto save addon link does not seem to work.

Comment: @Mobin Thank you ... updated