# How do I save a frame as an image in Blender 3.0 VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, saving

This question has already been answered [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/39022/16690), but everything got changed around in Blender 3.0.  F3 now opens up this search menu which has not been very useful in finding what I'm looking for.

I would like to save this individual frame as a PNG.  How do I do it in Blender 3.0?  My Interface -> Editors -> Temporary Editors -> Render In setting is set to "Keep User Interface", and I would like to keep it that way if possible.

[image]

Comment: The first answer shown under the question you've linked above gives you 4 options. None of them is _F3_, did you try any of these? Because the _F3_ answer is about five and a half years old, the one by vklidu just 9 months.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39022/how-to-save-render)

Comment: I see in the screenshot you show that you pressed `F3`over the video preview window, you are supposed to render the image with `F12` first then press `F3` over the rendered image.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka Oh, totally missed that looking at the screenshot. You're right.

Comment: Yes, that's why the the command search is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

you can still save it here:

[image]

I am using a mac so i don't know your shortcut, but you can see it right beside the menu entry.

**EDIT**

The default shortcut for it is <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. Shortcuts are Area specific so make sure you hover on the image when pressing this.