# Rendering smoke simulation as a png/exr with transparency

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I built a simple smoke/fire simulation, and chose the scene film to be transparent. When I view the render in the compositor, the transparency seems correct (the half-transparent regions of the smoke are letting the checkered texture through). It also correctly handles the transparency when layering images with alpha over.

However, when I try to save my image as PNG/EXR to be used in external editors (especially photoshop) it seems like the smoke does not get saved at all, and ends up as completely transparent.

How can I export what I see in the compositor in a format that enables me to perform the overlay/compositing in an external tool like Photoshop?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: my question wasn't about "how to save my render". I'm pretty well aware of how to do that. the question is specifically about transparency with smoke/fluid simulations and their handling in other apps. Thanks for the suggestion regardless

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39022/how-to-save-render)

Comment: Hi :). Yeah... PNG can't handle emissive transparent pixels, and PS can't reliably handle scene referred EXRs. I'd try TIFF 16-bit, works  reasonably well ;))

Comment: Btw this has been extensively discussed in many posts here. @susu and @ troy_s have some detailed answers on this :)

Comment: @JachymMichal I tried with TIFF 16 bit and it seems it my smoke sim is not loaded at all in photoshop, nor in Mac's quick look... any specific suggestions?

Comment: Also - Any links to specific posts discussing this? I saw a couple of them but they seem to refer to very old versions of Blender and things have changed since then

Comment: @AlbertPerkins Things in Blender may have changed, but not much in PNG and EXR file types, and since your question seems to be more about using the renders in other software then Blender (as your edit suggests), there's not much to do about it in Blender anyway. I don't know if this tutorial by Polyfjord is of any use for you since it's not fire on transparent background, but at least there is explained how to get the _Filmic_ view transform from Blender into DaVinci Resolve. Maybe you can use it somewhere else as well: [Real-time EXR Workflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-UjJqwwMJc8)