# Image not appearing in output folder when rendered

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, image

For some reason, when I press render and I have my output folder set, it doesn't render it there. How can I save my image to the output folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6769/599

Comment: @gandalf3 Yeah, I think so. CV'd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is to be expected. Blender doesn't render the images to the output folder by default. This is only used when you press the render animation button.

One thing you can do to output your image, is to press <kbd>F3</kbd> in the UV Image editor, and you'll get a promt to save the image. Sadly, it won't automatically save it to your output folder.

Another workaround, is to set the beginning and end frames to 1, and then press the render animation button. In that case, you'll get it rendered out to the folder you specified.

Comment: I thought it's worth mentioning **[File Ouput](https://www.blender.org/manual/composite_nodes/types/output/file.html)** node, which will save rendered image after **Render** pressed to the specified folder. Works for BI and Cycles.

Answer (score 2):

Pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> after rendering will allow you to manually save your still renders as images. By default, it will be .png, but you can change the format if desired.

Comment: Beat you to it by about a minute :)