# Rendering file wont appear

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, image

Im trying to make a cycles rendering test with HDRs but when i render an image it doesn't appear in the specified folder.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Picture im trying to render]

[image: Folder im trying to save it to]

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43178/image-not-appearing-in-output-folder-when-rendered?rq=1. This is as expected, thus no images will be in output folder even if it's setup in **Render** > **Output** rollout because you're rendering only one image. See more info in linked questions

Answer (score 2):

When you render images they don't export themselves to a folder, you have to do that manually. Just use the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> (with the mouse hovering over the render in the UV Image Editor) and navigate to the folder you want the image to export to.

Comment: Ive already specified the folder on "output" And when i try to click "play rendered animation" it comes with an error saying the file doesnt exist..

Comment: What are you actually doing? Are you rendering a single frame, an animation or something else?

Comment: I clicked "Render" and "Render Image"

Comment: @MartinLund  The output folder is only for animations, if you render a single frame you have to save it manually.  This can be done (in the UV/Image Editor) under *Image* > *Save as Image* or with [Shift]+[F3].