# Where did my file Save to?

Tags: rendering, file-browser

I'm using the Blender Video Editor. I finished, rendered it, and went to open the file, but I do not know where my file saved to!

I want it to be saved as a video file and I would like to know where it is, but I do not. I've already tried to look through all my folders, but I don't know if I'm checking the right place.

Comment: Check the Properties Editor > Render tab > Output rollout. Click there to open file browser which *should* be opened in the directory which contains that file. Other than that use OS system search and that's not Blender related then.

Comment: The default path should be the OS' temp path or `/tmp`. You can change that path (in your Properties, Render tab, Output panel) to something starting with a double forward Slash (like `//out`, the Frame range and file extension will then be appended) to get your Render output saved next to your *.blend*-file.

Answer (score 11):

The output settings determine where your video file (or image sequence) should be saved to:

2.7$x$$x$

[image]

For 2.8 look here:

[image]

---

If you are rendering a single image (By pressing render or <kbd>F12</kbd>) The image does not get saved automatically, you need to save it manually.

in 2.7$x$$x$ use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to save the image, or go to the UV/Image editor and Select Save Image

[image]

in 2.8$x$$x$ Use the image editor and select Save as (or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: Noting in case anyone is rendering still images: This only applies for animations. In case of stills, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6769/599