# How do I convert my file into an avi AFTER it being rendered

Tags: rendering, export, video

Someone asked this before, however, they had not rendered yet. After I rendered, my volume wasn't working, so I re-added it... everything's working now, I just need to convert it to a .avi.

This is for a Youtube Intro.

Image of my screen -- again, I have seen it before, but when I opened this morning, I messed with the screens like the amateur I am, I'm certain everything's there, and rendered.

Here's what I did;
I downloaded (http://ifreshd.com/top122-n52-blender285)
I then clicked a blender file, (http://prntscr.com/caanwr) which was found in the downloaded file.
I edited the blender text to say the name of my Call of Duty Clan
I checked to make sure the music was working, it was, and the animations were on beat.
I selected Render Animation. 
This took about 6 hours.
After that, I tested everything, the music wasn't working.
The music is now working, but I can't convert it into a .avi file and need help doing so.

Comment: Your question is unlclear. Did you render an image sequence and now you want to encode is as video? Read: [How to render an animation as video?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15145/1853)

Comment: @cegaton I'm new to blender... have been on here for less than 2 days, does that mean I have to render again?

Comment: @cegaton I hope the edit clarified as to what happened.

Comment: Still not clear on what it is you rendered for 6 hours... (An image of the ouptut settings would help to understand) **Please read** [where-did-my-file-save-to?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50875/where-did-my-file-save-to/50881#50881) . In any case use that file (or files) that you rendered and load it into the VSE, set the output to desired format and hit Ctrl F12 (or the animation button) to encode.

Comment: Additionally read: https://www.blender.org/manual/render/output/video.html#encoding-panel