# Where is the Render animation default save?

Tags: rendering, animation, file-browser

I just ended a render and I can't find the file.
I don't choose any folder/location for saving it, I just rendered with the default presets.

Now there is a thing. I opened ANOTHER blender file and start to render too. Do you think the file overwrite?

Please help :(

Comment: The default directory (if you dindn't touch your starting file) should be your temporary directory, but its exact location depends on your OS. Just open a new file and look at the output panel. Regarding the name, if the frame count it's the same for both animations, there is a chance it has been overwrited, or well... "they" have been overwrited..because by default the output file format is PNG, so you should look for frames (0001.png, 0002.png, 0003.png...).

Comment: They should try to save to the same folder by default, and `Overwrite` is enabled by default. You will need to re-render some frames at least, potentially all of one of them.

Comment: Read [Where did my file Save to?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50875/where-did-my-file-save-to/50881#50881)

Answer (score 1):

You have of to check the output tab to select the path where you want your animation to be saved. [image]

Answer (score 0):

**for OPENGL renders:**

first off C:\tmp for win7 with 2.78 That's where mine was.
second you can press

**control+F11**

to play the animation and it(the directory) should display at the top.

**For non OPENGL**:

select the camera
goto properties > Render(should be the first tab > Output

**The pythonic way:**

```
 import bpy
 x=bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.filepath
 print(x)
```