# Why can't I find my render?

Tags: rendering

I can't find my render anywhere. Now matter what folder I choose, when I go to that folder I don't find my render. And the only option left is to screenshot and crop or something. Please help. Blender version: 2.79

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add the following information: how are you rendering? Using F12, Ctrl+F12 or are you saving from the UV/Image editor (if so please describe how you are doing it). Please add an image of your output settings. Please show an image of whatever options you have.

Comment: maybe related: [Where did my file Save to?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50875/where-did-my-file-save-to)

Answer (score 1):

Blender sticks rendered images in `/tmp` on Mac and probably Linux. (I don't know about Windows.) It'll be called something like `0003.png`.

You can save your rendered image somewhere by pressing F3 (Fn+F3 on a laptop) instead of trying to dig for it. This also lets you conveniently name it.