# How to make image sequence?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I searched that image sequence is a faster way to make the video. But does it come out smooth? How do you make the image sequence at the first place? I only found tutorials of the conversion into avi file but not on how to make the images. Thanks for the help.

Edit: So, I already did the image sequence before but I couldn't find the image file. It only gives me a .Blend1 file.And I tried to convert it into .png file but it only changes the name rather than changing the format.
[image]

Help me.Thx.

Comment: Please tell us more about what you want to do and why, provide more context about your question.

Comment: sorry, im not a native english speaker and i am completely new to blender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the video will be smooth with the added benefit that you can process each image before creating the video from them.

1. First you need to create an animation sequence using key frames
2. By default Blender will save the animation as images, frame by frame after clicking the 'Animation' button as the image bellow. When you give the animation a name, before the clicking the 'Animation' button Blender will number the images in each image name for easy identification.
3. You can do composition in Blender or you can individually or batch process the images created for the animation, if you desire.
4. Switching Blender into Video Editing mode you import the images and create the video as in this YouTube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SNoV-EmDYw&t=2s. The actual video creation starts 1:15 in the tutorial

[image]

Comment: I already did before but i couldn't find the image file. It only gave me a .Blend1 file and I accidentally opened it with notepad that wouldn't let me to convert it into .png file. Thanks for the help.

Comment: the blend.1 file is an old version the project file, you cannot convert it to png. It is not an image. Your images will be saved in the path you set in the output file: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50875/where-did-my-file-save-to/50881#50881

Comment: It will save the file where the 'Output' is set, see image above