# How do you export a rendered 2D animation?

Tags: rendering, grease-pencil, 2d

I've been attempting to render my 2D animation by selecting "render", "render animation", but I can't see where to proceed from there.

Is there a way for me to save the render or export the animation as a video file rather than a .blend file?

Comment: The blend file is not video, it is the project file.  The output images or video will be where you set them in the output section of the properties window. Read: [where did my file save to?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50875/where-did-my-file-save-to)