# Where does the render output go?

Tags: rendering

I set up the render and have tried multiple 'write' locations...hell I even tried to send the output .png to the desktop...no joy...renders 1/2 an hour and I still can't locate a file. Help please.

Comment: Hi. Please only ask one question at a time.

Comment: If you use simple Render Image and don't setup anything in the compositing nodes, for example, then nothing will be saved automatically by default. To save rendered image open UV Image editor, press F3 to open File browser and choose location. Defined in the Render tab settings location will be used for rendering animations.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6769/no-file-output-after-rendering

Answer (score 0):

Check your output setting in the render tab:

[image]

after the image has rendered it will be in your UV editor, then you just need to save as:

[image]