# File Missing on Computer

Tags: animation, blend-files, saving

I rendered a file and it is saved under a tmp file, but I can not find it on my computer. Is there any way to change the file location or another way to find it?

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6769/599

Comment: Which OS?.  Default Ubuntu (for example) clears the tmp folder every reboot.  Can be altered to some time frame, which is (IMO) worth doing to still have autosaves in case of crash, but not have autosaves filling the tmp folder.