# Its possible to make Blender to autosave the Final Renders after these are finished?

Tags: rendering

Unfortunately, there has been blackouts in the place where i live and i've lost many renders more than once, so... it's possible to make Blender to autosave your finished Renders? or even after they are canceled? there's an option or addon or something?

Comment: Are you talking about still renders? You could always set the frame range to (1, 1) and then *Render Animation*. That way, the image will be saved even though the sequence only consists of 1 image.

Comment: Yes, still images. Cool, thanks for the Info, bro ^^

Comment: It is possible though by default you should do this manually (for still images). There's addon https://github.com/elfnor/blender_auto_save_on_render though I'm not aware if it works with recent Blender builds, see for more solutions https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6769/no-file-output-after-rendering