# Force each new render into sequential render slot

Tags: rendering

Is it possible to require each new <kbd>F12</kbd> render to appear in a new render slot thereby not overwriting the one I wanted to compare it against?

Comment: This seems relevant: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/463/logging-renders

Comment: All you need to do is change which render slot you have selected, is there any reason you need to automate this? Pressing `F12` and changing features is more time-consuming.

Comment: Well... if I am working in Object mode and making changes, I frequently hit F12 to see the results. If I remembered to move to the next open slot in the UV/Image view before doing so, the render appears inthe next slot. If not, the render is displayed in the slot in which the prior render is holding, overwriting it....

Comment: I see, you want to default to the next empty slot. That will take some scripting, which is out of my department :/ I wish you luck, I really would like that feature as well.

Comment: In a completely ideal new-feature world, I would love for the render Slots to be associated with the settings used to create each render... so I could make a render into Slot 1, make changes and render into Slot 2, and then move all settings back to the Slot 1 condition.... But at the moment I am just trying to render into the next open slot...

Comment: While not automatic there is keyboard navigation of the slots - 1-8 will take you to a specific slot. That's only one extra keypress before F12.

Answer (score 7):

here is a script that switch the render slot automatically after each render 
-This is for blender **2.72 and earlier** versions :

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def PostRender(self):
        bpy.data.images['Render Result'].render_slot += 1
        bpy.data.images['Render Result'].render_slot %= 7

bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.append(PostRender)
```

paste and run inside blender

---

as Ray Mairlot noted the [changes](https://developer.blender.org/rBS375d2dc85535b9f08fd2e854c80434eac1c28a67) in blender **2.73 and later** versions require replacing `render_slot` with `render_slots.active_index` as follows :

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def PostRender(self):
        bpy.data.images['Render Result'].render_slots.active_index += 1
        bpy.data.images['Render Result'].render_slots.active_index %= 7

bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.append(PostRender)
```

Comment: This is the right direction. But `render_slot` cannot take an `int` it needs a render slot type.

Comment: @RayMairlot so how should i do it ? also is there more convenient way to loop through the slots instead of this like slot.next() or something like that ?

Comment: I don't know. Did you not test the code?

Comment: @RayMairlot I did and it's running fine, I thought you can help me out make it better than this ?

Comment: You can't be running that code because it should be `render_slots` not `render_slot`

Comment: @RayMairlot well I guess you should try it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21418/discussion-between-ray-mairlot-and-chebhou).

Comment: This works perfectly, no errors or unexpected behavior. just run the script and you are good to go!

Comment: The script works for me! Renders and immediately hops into next slot. Very cool, and thank you!

Comment: @Chebhou Actually, I forgot, you can do just ` bpy.data.images['Render Result'].render_slot %= 8 `

Comment: Is it possible to change the slot before (at the same time) the render is launched, not after?

Comment: @Bithur there is a handler render_pre() that can do that i will try with it

Comment: This does not work in blender 2.77a on a Mac as of 1 September 2016. No error, no render, no change. Command line reports only: bpy.ops.text.run_script()