# How to save still renders straight to disk like animations?

Tags: rendering, image

Animation frames get saved to disk automatically. [image: Render button for animation]

Still images do not. [image: Render button for a single frame]

Is there a setting that can be changed so that single-frame renders also get saved to disk automatically upon completion?

To clarify, I mean changing the behavior of the render function, not simply changing the frame range to Start:1 End:1 (for example) and rendering as an animation.

Comment: You can use a file output node, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6769/599

Comment: @gandalf3 I never even heard of that one before o.O

Comment: @gandalf3 Ah, right. What I'm looking for though is more like a way to change the behavior for all .blend files, as a setting. I don't mean changing the startup .blend. Either something that can be quickly enabled in the Render context, enabled in Preferences, or maybe added custom as a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @Mentalist You might try [this addon](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/491/599)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is supported.

"**Write Image**" - it's an optional parameter of the operator, and can be set in the key-map editor.

*(Preferences > Input > search "render")*

In my case I have the shortcut for Render set to <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> so it looks like this:

[image: Write Image checkbox enabled]

Just make sure to specify a file name:

[image: Output file path]