# Disable saving render result to file system?

Tags: rendering, saving

Is there a way to prevent Blender from writing a file to the file system when rendering?

A weird question, I know, so let me give some background:

I'm using a plugin that hooks into the Freestyle renderer, and exports the generated Freestyle lines to third-party hardware (a laser projector). As soon as a scene is rendered, it is sent over network. Freestyle rendering can be a bit slow, and to make the process a bit closer to real time, I'm trying to find ways to optimise it. I've just realised that when an animation is rendered, Blender will also write all rendered images to disc, which is unnecessary for this application and just extra overhead. I can't find an option or workaround to disable saving the rendered images.

Comment: I don't think [that's the case for stills](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39703/how-to-save-still-renders-straight-to-disk-like-animations)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos you're correct, but I should have specified that this problem is particularly annoying when rendering animations. The "write image" checkbox is unchecked for my render animation hotkey, but it still writes an image to disc. Never knew key bindings had customisable options like that though so thanks!